# Why is performance better in a LinkedList when a reference type value and its node are created at the same time?

Tags: c#

This questions stems from the [MSDN page on LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) under "Remarks" (fifth line).

> Lists that contain reference types perform better when a node and its value are created at the same time. LinkedList accepts null as a valid Value property for reference types and allows duplicate values.

I have searched through the source code and nothing really stands out to me. Could it be that this line was once true but was just forgotten about? If not, then why is it the case?

Comment: If this is still true (if) this is most likely not a property of the list but of the way memory allocation works in general. Objects allocated close together in time are probably also close together in memory, improving locality of reference (and hence caching). Poor locality is already a weakness of linked lists that is worthwhile to keep to a minimum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that it has to do with [Locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

.NET uses a compressing garbage collector, that means that in case of reference type values, those would be allocated alongside its related `LinkedListNode<T>` in the actual RAM region. If you access the value right after reaching the node, there is a good chance the value is already in cache.

Comment: Though it would still be true without a compressing GC.

Comment: Depending on the actual allocation algorithm that *could* be true. As for the .NET garbage collector, it had improved locality of reference as one of its design goals.